# angular codeGen problemDetails.ts

Tags: angular, swagger, codegen

I use Swagger CodeGen and recently I changed the .jar CodeGen version from 2.3.1 to 2.4.2. Now I have a problem that rises every time I compil my solution.
The ng serve fails with that message :

```
ERROR in angularApp/app/core-module/providers/logbook/model/problemDetails.ts(16,18):
error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ERRORUNKNOWN' as a type.
```

The problemDetails.ts code is :

```
import { ERRORUNKNOWN } from './eRRORUNKNOWN';

export interface ProblemDetails {
  [key: string]: ERRORUNKNOWN | any;
     type?: string;
     title?: string;
     status?: number;
     detail?: string;
     instance?: string;
}
```

The only solution I found is remove the `ERRORUNKNOWN |`, but I have to do that every time I modify a controller in back side.

Does someone have an idea about what's wrong ?

Comment: You may consider switching to OpenAPI Generator (http://openapi-generator.tech) as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you @WilliamCheng but I want to give it a try before switching if there is not solution.